# read special time value in R

Tags: r

In R,

In a data frame I have some value in the form 0h 9min. 34sec.

I would like to use Strptime to read in those values. What format should I choose? ( like format= %a%b%c ,  I could not find any that could handle the characters behind those numbers).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just include them verbatim

```
strptime("0h 9min. 34sec", format="%Hh %Mmin. %Ssec", tz="UTC")
#[1] "2014-12-09 00:09:34 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative I suggest `lubridate`, which has a range of intuitive functions for working with dates and times.

```r
lubridate::hms("0h 9min. 34sec")
#> [1] "9M 34S"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>